# Custom list of client/node for private chain - Consortium blockchains

Tags: private-blockchain

I've been reading on making a custom private chains [here](https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html) , [here](http://billmarino2.github.io/general/2015/12/09/JURIX-2015-setting-up-an-ethereum-testnet.html) , [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network),[here](http://adeduke.com/2015/08/how-to-create-a-private-ethereum-chain/) and [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster) .

It's pretty clear how to create a custom chain and having remote client connect to the node with this :

```
geth attach                   # connect over IPC on default endpoint
geth attach ipc:/some/path    # connect over IPC on custom endpoint
geth attach http://host:8545  # connect over HTTP
geth attach ws://host:8546    # connect over websocket
```

But that's just a client connecting to the node.And not exactly another client running it's own node of my chain.

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a custom list of client(which are nodes) that can connect / use/ run a node of my privatenet but making it impossible for people outside that list from doing it.

Should that be done externally ? by restricting ip ? or can it be done any otherway? more internally ?

Any info / link for doing so is very welcome.

TLDR: I want a private chain with node 1 connected to node 2 connected to node 3 but managing who can connect to whom so that my data stays private but still need to be verified by multiple nodes to be included , much like what vitalik describe as a Consortium blockchain , [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/08/07/on-public-and-private-blockchains/)

Answer (score 3):

Make a static-nodes.json file as described here so that your nodes connect to each other.
https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html

Also firewall off your nodes at the network level so that they can only talk to each other. You can do this with:

- Individual firewall rules so traffic on the relevant port only goes in and out to the other nodes you specify
- A VPN, so they talk to each other on a private network and the relevant ports are only on that network.
- SSH tunnels kept alive with autossh or something.