# why contracts can't be deployed on my private chain using geth CLI?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment

I tried to use the geth CLI(the eth.contract command line) to deploy a new contract to my private chain, but why is there no response even no transactions received by the chain according to the log
and when I use that command line to deploy the contract there is no need for me to unlock the account or provide the passphrase
[image]

Comment: What command did you use to deploy the contract  ?

Comment: the method posed in this question,  the first answer  http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3511/2-mapped-structs-with-an-address-array-push-not-working/3652#3652

Comment: Can you start your ethereum node in --verbosity 6 mode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely caused by a locked account. Try adding the `--unlock 0 --password {passwordfile}` parameter as shown below.

---

From [geth --dev exposes live net accounts. Is it safe?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/geth-dev-exposes-live-net-accounts-is-it-safe) :

Here is my Dev startup script:

```
#!/bin/sh

geth --datadir ~/EtherDev/data --dev --nodiscover    \
  --mine --minerthreads 1 --maxpeers 0 --verbosity 3 \
  --unlock 0 --password ~/EtherDev/etc/passwordfile  \
  --rpc console
```

And here is the Dev script I use to create my passwords:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir ~/EtherDev/data
geth --datadir ~/EtherDev/data           \
  --password ~/EtherDev/etc/passwordfile \
  account new
```

And I just use a simple password in `~/EtherDev/etc/passwordfile`.

Comment: I unlock the account first and problem solved, thank you!