# My transactions are kind of stuck!

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, json-rpc, testnets, confirmations

I have sent this transaction to testnet through json-rpc with my geth node using eth_sendTransaction method and the following parameters:

```
"from": "0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d",
"to": "0x90e8682b63d7922a3e942d4bbd4c88095634a17b",
"value": "0xf4240"
```

// 0xf4240 = 1 million wei, 1 babbage

Geth node log receives the tx as showed here:

```
I0915 08:29:03.639166 eth/api.go:1193] Tx(0x2dac8edc68d40f2b09e2f06d455c51ea6f29a6199eeeccbff8b946f5c2e330d9) to: 0x90e8682b63d7922a3e942d4bbd4c88095634a17b
```

But transaction is not propagating through testnet ...

Two days ago this very same transaction (same from, to and value, but obviously not same txHash) was accepted (mined) in Ethereum testnet in less than 20 seconds. Today every transaction I sent seems to be stall.

The txHash assigned to the transaction is `0x2dac8edc68d40f2b09e2f06d455c51ea6f29a6199eeeccbff8b946f5c2e330d9` . On etherscan there's no info about it: https://testnet.etherscan.io/tx/0x2dac8edc68d40f2b09e2f06d455c51ea6f29a6199eeeccbff8b946f5c2e330d9

When I query the node about the tx with eth_getTransactionByHash method this is the result:

```
        [blockHash] => 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
        [blockNumber] => 
        [from] => 0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d
        [gas] => 0x15f90
        [gasPrice] => 0x4a817c800
        [hash] => 0x2dac8edc68d40f2b09e2f06d455c51ea6f29a6199eeeccbff8b946f5c2e330d9
        [input] => 0x
        [nonce] => 0x10000e
        [to] => 0x90e8682b63d7922a3e942d4bbd4c88095634a17b
        [transactionIndex] => 
        [value] => 0xf4240
```

It seems like it's waiting to be mined forever...

Has this transaction been brodcasted to testnet? Has it been mined? Why not? How can I track the mining status of this transaction?

After reading a similar question [Why are these transactions not broadcasted in my private network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6302/why-are-these-transactions-not-broadcasted-in-my-private-network) I realize I have unlocked from_account. Do I have to unlock to_account too?

It seems transactions became stuck on nonce 0x100004. Here it is the details of the previous tx (nonce 0x100003) and the tx with nonce 0x100004:

```
eth_getTransactionByHash: ["0x59af3aec8331c407a5a33a58203ee62a89b1efa772806b2c4319c395bb70bdd0"]
Array
(
    [jsonrpc] => 2.0
    [id] => 1
    [result] => Array
        (
            [blockHash] => 0x0aceab7d5e8a1d44efc36dfadabcbe3eaa14de08e7625a3208ca07fac6275014
            [blockNumber] => 0x190dce
            [from] => 0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d
            [gas] => 0x15f90
            [gasPrice] => 0x4a817c800
            [hash] => 0x59af3aec8331c407a5a33a58203ee62a89b1efa772806b2c4319c395bb70bdd0
            [input] => 0x
            [nonce] => 0x100003
            [to] => 0x90e8682b63d7922a3e942d4bbd4c88095634a17b
            [transactionIndex] => 0x0
            [value] => 0x2540be400
        )

)
eth_getTransactionByHash: ["0x824eeda61dba30c107400a5ab43dffa8408aae7f925f530699f69c94ed0c008b"]
Array
(
    [jsonrpc] => 2.0
    [id] => 1
    [result] => Array
        (
            [blockHash] => 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            [blockNumber] => 
            [from] => 0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d
            [gas] => 0x15f90
            [gasPrice] => 0x4e20
            [hash] => 0x824eeda61dba30c107400a5ab43dffa8408aae7f925f530699f69c94ed0c008b
            [input] => 0x
            [nonce] => 0x100004
            [to] => 0x90e8682b63d7922a3e942d4bbd4c88095634a17b
            [transactionIndex] => 
            [value] => 0x2540be400
        )

)
```

Well, thx for your comments, because I did it! Resending tx with nonce 0x100004 worked and has been mined. Thx!

Nevertheless, I still don't know why tx 0x824eeda61dba30c107400a5ab43dffa8408aae7f925f530699f69c94ed0c008b got stuck ... any hint about this could help me a lot. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your transaction info, the `nonce` is `0x10000e`, which, in the context of the test-net, means this is the 15th transaction. However, as seen on the [page of the `from` account](https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d), there have only been 4 transactions.

The miners will therefore not mine this new transaction before transactions with nonces `0x100004` to `0x10000d` show up.

How did you create this pending transaction?

Comment: Just calling json-rpc method eth_sendTransaction with the following parameters:

 "from": "0x3b877e80b5c0b29d88f3768ed4292b35fdd93a9d",
 "to": "0x90e8682b63d7922a3e942d4bbd4c88095634a17b",
 "value": "0xf4240"

Comment: So, I understand transaction with nonce 0x100004 is being the cause of the stuck, right? How can I find the reason why it has not been confirmed/mined?

Comment: It is the _absence_ of a transaction with nonce `0x100004` (to `0d`) that is holding up the one with `0e`.

Comment: When I send transactions I don't specify the nonce, should I? Who does control the nonce? I thought geth node automatically did it...

Comment: Yes, Geth is supposedly doing it automatically. What is your Geth command-line to start it?

Comment: geth --rpc --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --rpcport "8545" --testnet --etherbase "0x47978a69f..."

Comment: I have just added the details of the previous tx (nonce 0x100003) and the tx with nonce 0x100004 above in the question. Do you find anything wrong?

Comment: Are you mining on your own node too?

Comment: No, no mining, just syncing.

Comment: Well, thx for your comments, because I did it! Resending tx with nonce 0x100004 worked and has been mined. Thx!

Nevertheless, I still don't know why tx 0x824eeda61dba30c107400a5ab43dffa8408aae7f925f530699f69c94ed0c008b got stuck ... any hint about this could help me a lot. Thx anyway!

Comment: Careful, if you send enough transactions to get up to the correct nonce, that transaction will become valid again and could be resent. Obviously it's not a large amount, but if it were, you could lose money