# HELP to set up a private net with 3 nodes on the same machine or 3 different VM linux

Tags: private-blockchain, nodes, golang

i'm looking for a way to set up 3 node on a private net with Ethereum. I'm using Go as a Client .

I Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

please check how to setup a private chain [How do I set up a private ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network)
you need before to start to check if the communication(ping) between the VMs is ok.