# How to experiment with Ethereum without downloading the entire blockchain?

Tags: clients, light-clients, java, spv

I want to experiment with Ethereum without having to download the *entire* blockchain. My ISP limits my bandwidth to 50GB and downloading the ETH chain would consume a lot of that, not to mention the time. Is there any SPV like implementation of Ethereum? With Bitcoin, I could simply download bitcoinj and start coding.

I have also considered Blockchain as a Service by Azure. Are there any alternatives? (because they need my credit card number.)

What I want to do:

1. Experiment with simple transactions (sending Ether)
2. Create contracts
3. Store arbitrary data on blockchain.

Ideally I would prefer something that runs on JVM but that is not a hard constraint.

One method I have in mind is to run a private blockchain using Ethereum code but with my own genesis block. Will this approach work with other 3rd party Ethereum frameworks (such as Truffle)?

Comment: Check out truffle. Allies you to easily use testrpc, testnet, and main net, and switch between them easily.

Answer (score 9):

### Creating a local in-memory blockchain ([Ganache](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache))  with `Brownie` is recommended way for development.

Besides `Browser Solidity` (as @Rob Hitchens recommended), you could also develop smart contracts using `Brownie`. You could implement your smart contracts and test it on its local blockchain, where each transaction will be deploy right away and increment the block number.

> **Brownie:** A python framework for Ethereum smart contract deployment, testing and
> interaction. https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io

---

In addition to that you could also create your own private ethereum network, where blockchain will start from genesis block. If you build it as Proof-of-Authority you can fix time to 10-15 seconds for block time and and it will not consume any additional CPU usage.

If you are required to experiement on a private chain, you can connect and use **freely** a proof-of-authority private ethereum network ([**eBlocPOA**](http://ebloc.cmpe.boun.edu.tr:3015)) that I have started and using, please see the [guide](https://github.com/ebloc/eBlocPOA) to connect and feel free to contact with me through the github link.

You could also find some guide to start your own private-chain:

- https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2571/4575
- https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html

Comment: Creating private chain with Populus is recommended way for development, as public chain is way too slow to be useful for local development.

Comment: `Populus` is longer maintained, it references `Brownie` to use

Answer (score 5):

You can connect to a remote ethereum node such as [INFURA](http://www.infura.io/), using the [JSON RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC), so you won't need to worry about maintaining and synchronizing a local node.

You can see this guide about [using Truffle with INFURA](http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/using-infura-custom-provider)

Disclaimer: INFURA Founder here.

Comment: That's not a disclaimer: you should be proud of it!

Answer (score 4):

You can work with Browser Solidity. It let's you experiment with Smart Contracts, compile them, run them and debug them using an in-memory execution environment (default), or the real thing. https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/

testRPC is a sort of blockchain emulator that's very popular with developers. It will initialize a bunch of accounts and respond like a real blockchain would (mostly), but much faster.

Agree with Avatar, a private chain is another step toward realism before contending with the weight of testnet and the real thing. You can create a network as small as one node mining all by itself and test against that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ganache](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache) to run a lightweight local ethereum instance on your computer. It's probably the best option if you start programming with its integrated block explorer and flexibility.