# What gets mined in a private test network?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, blocks

I followed the instructions in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2571/592)  answer to get a private testnet.

When I start mining in dev/private network using miner.start() what exactly is being mined?

Since I am the only node in the test network and I am not sending any transaction, I don't understand what the newly mined blocks contain!

Is the network supposed to mine a block every x seconds even if there is no transaction in the network?

Comment: In answer to your final question: yes :-)

Comment: why is it so? Isn't it wasteful to add blocks having the same state as the previous one? Wouldn't it increase the size of the blockchain needlessly?

Comment: Adding new blocks to the chain increases the security of any previous blocks that contain transactions, as it makes it economically more difficult to change older blocks by creating a new version of the chain. In your case you have no blocks that contain any transactions, but the code has no intelligence to know this.

Comment: okay makes sense! But won't the merkle roots of 2 blocks be same if there is no state change across them?

Comment: I suppose the root of the state trie will be the same, but other things will be different in the block header. (Or have I missed your point?)

Comment: You mentioned that the code has no intelligence of knowing that a block contains no transaction! But checking the merkle root and equating it with the previous block merkle root will tell the code that the new block has no transaction right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58445/discussion-between-pd176-and-richard-horrocks).