# Geth server - How to run lightweight server?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

I am doing test development to run smart contracts on Ethereum client. I downloaded geth, but still unable to setup geth client. I run geth command and it keeps on running for next 10 minutes. I think it is downloading the whole Ethereum block chain on my computer. I killed it fearing it may blow up my computer. Please tell me how to download the light version so that I can run test my smart contracts? Went through various articles on internet, but not able to find solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

geth won't blow up your laptop it will only fill up your hard drive if you sync it with the full blockchain. the light mode wich is available since v1.5.2 helps you to synch with blockchain without downloading it, you get only the current state so it reduce the size needed.

to use the light mode, download geth and run it using the option light

```
geth --light
```

if you want to test your contract setup a private chain or connect to the testnet.

Comment: How light is geth --light? Can I specify number of nodes in the end? I did run geth --light, but had to close after 5 minutes as I thought it should take 1 minute or 2 to setup geth

Comment: Secondly how do I setup a private chain or connect to the testnet?

Comment: private chain : https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network

Comment: testnet :you use geth --testnet

Comment: your geth node will be continually synching and downloading data even in the light mode the difference is about the size of the data to download if you don't so set up your private chain (local) where you can start stop synching at your will