# How to use a private network in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, dapps

I am following this answer:

[How do I set up a private ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network)

but my result of `miner.start()` will return `null`

Is it because my geth version is `1.6.6-stable`?

Also welcome any beginner's guide to develop dApp.

Comment: After I type miner.start(), I found my Mist wallet mining in main network.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I run my private network using geth on Ubuntu:

Create a simple genesis.json file, e.g.

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 1907,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
  "difficulty": "40",
  "gasLimit": "2100000",
  "alloc": {}
}
```

Create a first node and make sure it works:

```
$ mkdir node1
$ geth --datadir node1 account new
$ geth --datadir node1 account new
$ geth --datadir node1 init genesis.json
$ geth --datadir node1 --networkid 98765 console
> miner.start(1)
```

Once you have done some mining on this node, stop the miner with `miner.stop()` (This isn't absolutely necessary but it is just convenient so you don't see too many info messages appearing in the console while trying to copy/paste the enode address, coming up next).

Make sure you know the enode address of the first node, you will need this to connect your second node:

```
> admin.nodeInfo
{  enode: "enode://08993401988acce4cd85ef46a8af10d1cacad39652c98a9df4d5785248d1910e51d7f3d330f0a96053001264700c7e94c4ac39d30ed5a5f79758774208adaa1f@[::]:30303", 
...
```

Let's do the same steps now to set up second node:

```
$ mkdir node2
$ geth --datadir node2 account new
$ geth --datadir node2 account new
$ geth --datadir node2 init genesis.json
$ geth --datadir node2 --networkid 98765 --port 30304 --bootnodes "enode://08993401988acce4cd85ef46a8af10d1cacad39652c98a9df4d5785248d1910e51d7f3d330f0a96053001264700c7e94c4ac39d30ed5a5f79758774208adaa1f@127.0.0.1:30303" console
```

Notice that we had to change [::] to the IP address of the host.

Once you start this node, wait for a little while and then you will eventually see the blocks that you mined on your first node being synced over.

I have written up more of my experiences getting started with geth, private network and smart contract here in case you want more details: https://alanbuxton.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/first-steps-with-ethereum-private-networks-and-smart-contracts-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: These instructions were very helpful for a basic miner but my second node is not connecting to the first, and vice-versa.  `admin.peers` returns an empty set.  I'll have to start a new thread to see if I can figure that out.

Answer (score -1):

I too have a private testnet working pretty OK till now. I am yet to start dApp development though - in fact, I require a good enough dApp tutorial. As far as your `miner.start()` returning `null` is concerned, that is pretty much alright. Ideally yes, it should return `true`, but if it doesn't, please check if the system is mining using the command `eth.mining`. If it is returning `true`, it means the blocks are getting mined.

Also keep in mind that if `eth.mining` is true for a very long time, say an hour or two, but `eth.blockNumber` still returns 0, it is because mining requires at least a minimum of 4GB RAM. So if you're on a virtual machine, make sure you give it enough RAM.

Comment: null is the correct return code for miner.start()