# Truffle Migrate with my own ethereum Network

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-migration

I am developing ethereum contract. so I have set up ethereum server. I used this

`geth --rpc console --datadir "ethdata" --networkid xxxxx --nodiscover --rpcaddr "xx.xx.x.xxx" -rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain * --rpcapi "web3,net,personal,eth" attach http://0.0.0.0:8545 mygenesis.json`
to run ethereum server.

Ethereum server is working fine.

then I set up truffle with testrpc which is working fine. I try to truffle with my ethereum server. it displays like following

Expecting result:

```
finish migrate.
```

Actual result:

```
#truffle migrate
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
Deploying Migrations...
```

nothing happened for a long time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the geth.ipc file location and in another terminal window run geth attach command -

```
geth attach ipc://path_to_ipc_file/geth.ipc
```

After that unlock your default account -

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, 'password', 0)
```

and then run following command -

```
miner.start()
```

Your truffle migrations shall start working then.

Comment: where can i see geth.ipc file in my local machine

Comment: When you start your geth node, you will see some logs. One of them would be like this - INFO [06-29|00:20:54] IPC endpoint opened: /home/sanchitb/Workspace/pnet/geth.ipc

That's your geth.ipc path.

Comment: or you can also locate your geth.ipc file in your machine.

Comment: HI sanchit, Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /home/blockchain/blockchain/ethdata/geth.ipc: connect: no such file or directory
i got this error. that geth.ipc file is not in specified folder. how can i create geth.ipc file

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network/16306#16306

I did answer a similar question, on how to setup private net. That should help. If not then let's discuss on chat.

Comment: yes dude. i need ur help. can we chat?

Comment: join this chat - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61282/geth-issue