# truffle migrate with testrpc vs geth testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, testrpc

Truffle migrate works when I use testrpc but not geth.

Here's what I did for testrpc:
In one console

```
node-modules/.bin/testrpc
```

In another

```
truffle console
compile
migrate
```

resulting in

```
Using network 'development'.

Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying GoodFund...
  GoodFund: 0x18c9f7f2468714dab06264cf06446f66251ac930
Saving successful migration to network...
Saving artifacts...
```

However when I use

```
geth --testnet console
admin.startRPC("127.0.0.1", 8545, "*", "web3,db,net,eth")
personal.newAccount('blah')
personal.unlockAccount('account key', 'blah', 15000)
```

and in another console

```
truffle  migrate
```

resulting in

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: authentication needed: password or unlock
```

I've tried changing truffle.js host from 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' and got the same error.

This is what I have in 2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var GoodFund = artifacts.require("./GoodFund.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(GoodFund, '0x6196bc7c252ac811ce06824cd5abbbe4b36db6dc', {gas:4000000});
};
```

Thanks for y'alls help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to unlock the default account in case of geth which you created at the time of node setup probably using the following account  -

```
geth --datadir path_to_dir/ account new
```

You can unlock the default account like this -

```
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], 'password', 0)
```

If you don't remember the default account password, then I'd recommend you to setup the geth node again, unlock the default account and run `truffle migrate`.

You can follow the steps mentioned in this answer to do private net setup - [How do I set up a private ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network/16306#16306)