# how to initialize a account in genesis.json file and fund it some money before mining?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc

in ethereum page of github,we can see something about genesis file below:

> Defining the private genesis state
>
> First, you'll need to create the genesis state of your networks, which
>   all nodes need to be aware of and agree upon. This consists of a small
>   JSON file (e.g. call it genesis.json):
>
> ```
> {
> "config": {
> "chainId": 0,
> "homesteadBlock": 0,
> "eip155Block": 0,
> "eip158Block": 0
> },
> "alloc" : {},
> "coinbase" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
> "difficulty" : "0x20000",
> "extraData" : "",
> "gasLimit" : "0x2fefd8",
> "nonce" : "0x0000000000000042",
> "mixhash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
> "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
> "timestamp" : "0x00"
> }
> ```
>
> The above fields should be fine for most purposes, although we'd
>   recommend changing the nonce to some random value so you prevent
>   unknown remote nodes from being able to connect to you. If you'd like
>   to pre-fund some accounts for easier testing, you can populate the
>   alloc field with account configs:
>
> "alloc": { "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {"balance":
>   "111111111"}, "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002":
>   {"balance": "222222222"} }

I define "alloc": {
"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": {"balance": "111111111"}
} in my genesis.json file, then I run command below:

./geth --datadir ethereum init genesis.json

but in geth console, after I run eth.accounts, it returns null

```
instance: Geth/helloworld/v1.6.6-unstable/linux-amd64/go1.8.3
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> eth.accounts
[]
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the steps given in the answer link below to create a private net and the steps also include how to fund your default account while initializing genesis block.

Basically, you need to allocate balance in Genesis file to an account which you might have created using this command -

```
geth --datadir pnet/ account new
```

Please take a look at this answer for the steps - [How do I set up a private ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network/16306#16306)