# Is it necessary to import all headers when making private Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

[image]

I am trying to make private block chain. [I am following this link](https://hackernoon.com/heres-how-i-built-a-private-blockchain-network-and-you-can-too-62ca7db556c0)

Comment: Hi there. What command did you use to start Geth? If it's a brand new private chain, there shouldn't be any data to sync.

Comment: @RichardHorrocks thanks for replying. I ran "geth — identity “yourIdentity” — init /path_to_folder/CustomGenesis.json — datadir /path_to_your_data_directory/ACPrivateChain" this command

Comment: Just to check - did you substitute values into each of the parameters? i.e. Did you substitute something for "yourIdentity"? There's a part in the link you referenced about network IDs - have you tried doing that?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I have substitute values but still it was syncing, now i am trying commands written below on that same post (the network ID command). Please suggest me any good link to proceed with setting up private ethereum block chain

Comment: Have a look at this previous question and answers for some other ideas: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-do-i-set-up-a-private-ethereum-network (Some of the answers are quite old, but the general idea should be the same.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is importing all the headers that means its syncing with public block chain.

So to make private blockchain. Please follow below steps

1. create genesis.json
2. run on mac terminal - "geth init path_to_geneis/genesis.json"
3. then to start your private network run - "geth -networkid=111 console" [111: choose any unique number for network id]
4. your console for private network will get open. now you can proceed !!

Thanks in advance.