# geth init and mining

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, block-reward

To set-up a private network with a given genesis document, I can start with the `init` command or start mining. With `init` and an account already existing, I can see the block created from the console (`eth.getBlock('latest')`). Mining would, of course, create the block  (`miner.start(1)` and also credit the reward to an `etherbase` account or the `eth.accounts[0]`. So,

1. Does `init` trigger a mining?
2. Who receives the reward for the genesis block when created with an `init`?

References:

[Creating the genesis block](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network)

[How do I set up a private ethereum network?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/125/3137)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `init` does not trigger mining. Init creates the first block in your blockchain. miner.start() does start mining process, if you have set a `coinbase` account

2) Nobody receives the reward for the genesis block. The reward is given to the account 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 , but this account is invalid

Comment: So the genesis block created from an `init` was not mined unless it was created out of `miner.start(1)`? I mean, as far as genesis block creation is concerned how is initialization and mining different?

Comment: if you start `geth` without init it is going to attempt to mine Ethereum's Main Net blockchain, not your private blockchain. do a `eth.getBlock(0) and see the hash of the block, it must be the hash of your genesis not the  0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3

Comment: initialization is required before mining so the node knows what blockchain is it working with. `geth` skips the `init` process to make it easier to join Ethereum's Main Net, but for private chains you have to do `init` when you create the node.

Comment: So, `init` is a per-requisite for mining in private networks. Thanks!